# Android Studio Ui test gives an error when enabling Java 8

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-studio-3.2

I tried on Android Studio 3.2.1 and Android Studio 3.4
If I enable Java 8 in gradle file and run espresso test, I receive this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeExceptionCause: java.lang.RuntimeException
```

After many trials, I found that removing Java8 support from gradle files fixes the issue.

But java 8 is important for my project. Do you have a better solution?

This is my code:

```
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest;
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import com.dubizzle.workshopsample.R;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MainActivityUiTest {

  @Rule
  public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule
      = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

  @Test
  public void testShareButtonClickedUi() {
    Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.txtStatus))
        .check(matches(withText("Hello World!")));

    Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.btnShare)).perform(click());

    Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.txtStatus))
        .check(matches(withText("onShareButtonClicked")));
  }
}
```

full error:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebugAndroidTest'.     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:596)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:130)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:210)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:140)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:115)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:42)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)    at
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.getInitalGraphData(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:162)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.lambda$makeDesugaringGraph$2(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:134)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringGraphs.forVariant(DesugaringGraphs.java:50)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.makeDesugaringGraph(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:132)
>     at
>   com.google.common.base.Suppliers$NonSerializableMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:160)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.getAdditionalPaths(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:111)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:325)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
>     ... 110 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitModule(ClassVisitor.java:148)     at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:731)    at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:632)    at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)    at
>   com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:144)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyzeJar(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:92)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:63)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.lambda$getInitalGraphData$4(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:150)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

Comment: Which java 8 features are you using? How are you enabling Java 8 in your build script? You should not need retrolambda OR min SDK 24, unless you're using some APIs that aren't available on lower SDK versions.

Answer (score 0):

according to this: [Use Java 8 language features](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)  you can only have a

> subset of Java 8 language features that vary by platform version.

You could try to raise the minSdkVersion and see if it helps (24 or higher).

> Android Studio does not support all Java 8 language features, but more are being added in future releases of the IDE. Depending on which minSdkVersion you’re using, certain features and APIs are available.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for your case but in mine adding retrolambda to the project fixed the issues. (Lambdas are the one language feature I am after.)

The only side effect is the build script spitting out a recommendation to remove retrolambda during each compilation, and really I expect this to be a temporary solution until google fix the issue.